# How to use the 3-D scale/rotate tool to create depth in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, patterns

I've a very simple rectangular shape that has been filled with a hexagon texture. I'm looking to create a sense of depth by keeping the lowermost row of the hexagons largest while transforming the top row to be smaller so they are appear to be in the distance.

This would be similar to creating a chessboard like 3-D feel. Any recommendations or proper ways to use the tool without relocating the actual placement of the rectangle – just be inner dimensions?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the pattern? What program are you working in?

Comment: I voted to close this and posted a new answer at the duplicate Alex indicated above.